# A reference in filesystem to the used DTB file

Tags: embedded-linux, device-tree

I'm wondering if, in a embedded linux board after the initial booting phase, if I surfing the filesystem using the terminal, is there a place where I can read which dtb file is currently in use from my system? A log stored in filesystem or something similar?

Comment: you mean /proc/device-tree?

Comment: The Linux kernel is typically not aware of any boot details, e.g. what was the boot medium/device.  The  kernel is simply provided with the **dtb** (device tree blob or binary) in a memory buffer. No name, reference, or origin is provided to the kernel for the **dtb**.  The only DT information available is the DT itself in **/proc/device-tree**, as already mentioned.  If you think about it, it's the actual contents of the DT that are salient, rather than "*which dtb file*" was loaded since filenames get reused.